# Way to optimize a condition "if (m == 0 || n == 0)"

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, bit-manipulation

I'm writing a function and this is what I have so far:

```
template <typename T> 
M2SA(T* A, size_t m, T* B, size_t n)
{
    /* Require both arrays be nonempty */
    if (m == 0 || n == 0)
    {
        throw ("Cannot find median of 2 sorted arrays if either is empty!";)
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can optimize the condition `if (m == 0 || n == 0)` using bit comparison operations ???

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil, [Donald Knuth].

Comment: Is the condition check actually your program's bottleneck?!

Comment: @40two: Wow, how did you figure out the OP's name?!

Comment: If the condition check was the bottleneck, then I bet the function call is an even a bigger bottleneck...

Comment: @KerrekSB Only Donald Knuth would have made such a question :P

Comment: Why do you think you can optimize anything there, the compiler doesn't optimize already (branch prediction, etc.)??

Comment: @40two: Well, Knuth is frantically working on several more volumes of books. It's entirely reasonable that he's having a deadline crisis and is turning to SO for content.

Comment: who's Donald Knuth? Do you know @KerrekSB?

Comment: @KerrekSB LOL! ;) that's a good one ...

Comment: "about 97% of the time"- Donald Knuth

Comment: This is a trick question because the median of a sorted array and an empty array is clearly the median of the sorted array.

Comment: Why use bit operations? Why not consider a solution that leverages the cloud?

Comment: @GuySirton, "If you think you are in the 3%, you are really in the 97%" - Steve Jobs.

Comment: @Jefffrey Ha.  I never heard this version.  Coming from a great developer such as Steve we should all take heed.  Anyways, my beef is with the selective quoting of Knuth, not so much the determination of whether this is a 3% or 97% case.

Comment: I would optimise the *readability* of this particular line of code by using descriptive names instead of "a" and "b". Now that would be an optimisation worth the trouble...

Comment: If the values of `m` and `n` are not big enough to worry about overflow, you could change the condition to `(m * n == 0)`.

Comment: You need two functions, one which calls the exception and another which finds the median. Store pointers to both functions in an array with two elements. Element zero contains pointer to "exception function". You then use array_element = (m == 0 & n == 0) to access the correct function. This would eliminate conditional branching?? Just additional overhead of pointer indirection for function call.

Comment: You could change it to `if ((m | n) == 0)`, but I don't see where it would buy you much. Come to think of it, I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler made that transformation with optimization at the highest level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before changing a line of code, set your compiler's optimization settings to high and view the assembly language.

I don't see how you can optimize the expression: `((m == 0) || (n == 0))` and squeeze more than negligible time out of it.  A data cache miss or an instruction cache reload would be equal performance or more slower than executing both sub-expressions.

Here's the expanded meaning (not necessarily optimal):

```
if (m == 0)
{
  throw (/*...*/);
}
else  // m != 0
{
  if (n == 0)
  {
    throw (/*...*/);
  }
}
```

The best solution is a solution with the fewest branch instructions.

The assembly language for the expanded version comes out to:

```
; optional:  move m into register 0
  compare register 0 to zero.
  branch, if equal, to Throw.
; optional:  move n into register 1
  compare register 1 to zero.
  branch if not equal to Continue
Throw:
  call throw_mechanism;
Continue:
```

Building a *truth table* for the instruction count:

```
  m   |  n    |  instructions processed
------+-------+-------------------
  0   |  N/A  |  2
 !0   |  0    |  4
 !0   |  != 0 |  4
```

The first two instructions for `m` are always processed:  fetched and evaluated.
The cases where `m != 0` causes 4 instructions to be fetched and evaluated.

So the average and worst case is 2 extra instructions are executed.

Assuming an instruction processing rate of 50 nanoseconds per instruction, you are saving 100 nanoseconds on the best case and the worst case is using 200 nanoseconds.

As I stated earlier, a data cache hit or a reloading of the instruction pipeline (cache) may take more than 200 nanoseconds (the worst time case).

**Summary**
Because the optimization of the given expression produces negligible outcome and applies to a very small section of code, it is called a *microoptimization*.  If `m` or `n` are not in the data cache or must be loaded from memory, the time required to fetch both values from memory will probably be equal to or more than the time required to process the extra instructions, using up any time gained by optimizing the expression.  Similarly if the instruction pipeline or cache need to be reloaded.  The time saved by optimizing this expression is wasted in the time researching the optimization or in other code waiting for an external entity (such as mouse click or hard drive I/O).

In other words, you and your program would benefit more from making your code more robust and working correctly than worry about trivial optimizations like this one.

Comment: Also would be worth to leave a word about the semantical flaw: `throw ("Cannot find median of 2 sorted arrays if either is empty!";)`.

Answer (score 13):

> Is there any way I can optimize the condition `if (m == 0 || n == 0)` (using bit operations)???

The answer is a resounding no for just about every platform, unless either `m` or `n` are extremely likely to be 0 and the arguments are not passed in registers:
The compiler will produce optimal code if you ask for optimization, most likely something along the lines of:

```
(load first argument into register)
(load second argument into register)
logical-and both arguments (not bitwise-and)
jump to throw statement if the zero-flag set
```

Two instructions for both tests! AFAIK, there are no platforms where that is not optimal.
There is a case i which the compiler can optimize even more: If it inlines the function, it can propagate constants, which might make the condition constant.

Anyway, the exception message in your code shows that you are testing the wrong condition, you want `!m && !n`.
Just about the same comments apply.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected wrong answer.

A way to lower the branch and instruction count is to use a bitwise AND:

```
if ( 0 == n * m )
{
    ...
}
```

Multiplication is fast and can be vectorized easily by the compiler, if placed in a simple loop.
The resulting Assembly consists of 3 instructions including the jump.

```
MUL a,b // assume a and b are registers
TEST a
JNZ after_the_if_scope
//throw code

after_the_if_scope:
...
```

Having said that, the statistics of the result (true or false) will affect the performance more, as a branch misprediction costs more than the actual computation in many cases.

Also note that if `m` and `m` are not plain integers but costly function calls, you should stay with logical or to avoid evaluating the 2nd function.

Comment: Careful! `==` has a higher precedence than `&` for historical reasons.

Comment: Also, a comment on [a deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23897105/200291) very similar to yours on this question asks, rightfully: “what about `m = 1` and `n = 3`?”

Comment: Always happen when answering late at night. I corrected my answer.

Comment: Better! But what if `m = n = ((size_t)1) << (sizeof(size_t) * CHAR_BIT / 2)`?